# Durandal HotTowel template for unix

Tags: durandal, single-page-application, hottowel

Of coure, I'm referring to John Papa's famous [HotTowel](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) template, does anyone have a working sample that can work on unix systems without the dependencies on ASP.net and VisualStudio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [standard durandal](http://durandaljs.com/downloads.html) html started kit instead. And then bring the bits you want to use in your app from HotTowel